# Как настроить функцию передвижения кружочка?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция которая отвечает за перемещение, кружочка по тач-событиям. Но проблема в том, что курсор то обгоняет сам кружочек то отстает.

Как сделать так, чтоб кружочек двигался равномерно, вслед за пальцем при этом не обгонял и не отставал ?

Сам код :

```js
var target;

$('.circle').on("touchstart", function() { 
target = $(this);
});

var moove = function (obj, x, y){
  $(obj).css({"left" : x });
  $(obj).css({"top" : y });
}
    
 $(window).on("touchmove", function(e) {  
   moove($(target), event.targetTouches[0].screenX, event.targetTouches[0].screenY ); 
 });
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: green;
  position:   absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle"> </div>
```

фидл: https://jsfiddle.net/dxnxpybe/21/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А Вы пробовали изменить `screenX` и `screenY` на `clientX` `clientY`, вроде как кружочек следует за пальцем.

```
var target;

$('.circle').on("touchstart", function() { 
  target = $(this);
});

var moove = function (obj, x, y){
  $(obj).css({"left" : x });
  $(obj).css({"top" : y });
}

$(window).on("touchmove", function(e) {  
  moove($(target), event.targetTouches[0].clientX, event.targetTouches[0].clientY ); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/appcscme/1/